# Can I use a wildcard SSL Certificate on an AWS free tier EC2 instance without ELB?

Tags: ssl, iis, amazon-ec2

Question:  is there any known issue with installing wildcard certs versus other certs directly a free tier EC2 instance, or is that something I should expect to work?

(I asked this because I was trying to eliminate it as a possibility while debugging an SSL install problem.  The problem turned out to likely be operator error (mine) so I deleted those details and just answered the main question, which I hope might be useful to other people.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES, because I was finally able to do it.  The port https binding is in place, and the pages respond to https.